# GPU is overheating after re-applying thermal paste

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, cooling, overheating

After dusting my computer (not vacuum cleaner), and re-applying new thermal paste on EVGA GTX 660 SC, it gets overheated, while before it wasn't.  Temperatures: before: idle - 40, max - 85-90, after: idle - 40, max - 100. What should I do?

Comment: I do not think that your "Sone DVD ROM" or the "Card Reader" are relevant. Could you edit the post so it contains the useful information (only) and some decent whitespace rather than a wall of text?

Comment: Ok, so I edited my question. What should I do?

Comment: Maybe you have applied too much thermal paste?

Comment: Two rice-sized lines. Could it be too much?

Comment: I think so. Also try to tweak fan control.

Comment: Yeah, I tryed to tweak it with EVGA's Precision program. Even when GPU fan is 100% and game graphics are pretty simple (World of Tanks) it easly climbs up to 95 Celsius. I'll try to re-apply thermal paste again.

Comment: Good luck :D Just don't put too much.

Comment: Ok, I'll post my results here after TIM replacement.

Comment: Which paste did you use?

Comment: First I used Nexus TMP-1000. Now the new results with unknown manufacturer TIM: Idle - 35-38, MAX - 82. So it really was TIM, that was causing the problem. Thank you everyone for help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common problem with thermal paste is applying too much.

What the paste is meant to do is minimize "stuff" between the CPU and the heatsink. This stuff can be air, or thermal paste.

Pastes like Artic Silver should be no more than a small pea in the center, then coated evenly. Other pads are measured for your socket and should be fool-proof.

Another possibility is that you should have used a good alcohol to clean the CPU and Heatsink before applying, otherwise you will not have a good contact between the CPU and HSF.